# Overriding Sass variables

Tags: css, variables, sass

I have a Sass file which does multiple imports as follows

```
@import("variables")
@import("custom-variables")
@import("widgets")
@import("custom-styles")
```

I declare a variable called $promoBoxColor for example in both variables and custom-variables, and then the widgets and custom styles references this variable.

What I am finding is that the color defined in variables is being used if I try and use it in custom-styles, not the colour defined in custom-variables.

Is it possible to override variables in this way in Sass? It seems to work fine if I just override a color used in widgets.

Comment: Is the variable that's defined in custom-variables set as a default?  ie. `$foo: someval !default`?

Comment: That's exactly how variable overriding works in SASS (Imports actually behave as if merging all the files into one big file, see the [reference](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html). Are you sure you don't have a typo either? You might also want to post the structure of the code around the declarations and usage of the variable, like for example the selector scope. This could help us helping you.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the replies. Found the best way of doing this was to set all the variables in the core variables file with !default and then declare the custom-variables first.